# System.reflection.targetexception non-static method requires a target

Tags: reflection, system, non-static

```
     public IQueryable<DebitorProductCautionsEx> GetEx(
            Expression<Func<DebitorProductCautions, bool>> filter = null,
            SearchDto search = null,
            int? lawyerID = null,
            bool? IsInDetailTab = null
            )
        {
            filter = filter ?? (p => true);
            search = search ?? new SearchDto();
            IsInDetailTab = IsInDetailTab ?? false;

//this line about authorization
            var hyDepList = context.Department.Where(p => p.ID == UserData.iDepartmentId && p.ID != 0).RecursiveSelect(p => context.Department.Where(pd => pd.ParentID == p.ID).AsQueryable<Department>()).Select(p => p.DepartmentBankCode).Distinct().ToList();

//this line about authorization
            var associatedDepartmenList = (from depID in context.DepartmentUserAssociation.Where(p => p.AssociateAccountUserID == UserData.iUserId && p.AssociateAccountUserID != 0).Select(p => p.DepartmentID)
join dep in context.Department on depID equals dep.ID
select dep.DepartmentBankCode).Distinct().ToList();

            var query = from item in dbSet.Where(filter)
                        join debitor in context.Debitor on item.DebitorID equals debitor.ID
                        //kurumsal
                        from debitorProducts in context.DebitorProducts.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.DebitorID == debitor.ID).OrderBy(a => a.TrackingDate).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from product in context.Product.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.ID == debitorProducts.ProductID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        //bireysel
                        from debitorProducts2 in context.DebitorProducts.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.ID == item.DebitorProductsID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from product2 in context.Product.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.ID == debitorProducts2.ProductID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from delegationDebitorProduct in context.MainLawyerDelegationDebitorProduct.Where(p => (p.DebitorProductID.HasValue && ((debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 3 || debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 8) ? p.DebitorProductID == debitorProducts2.ID : p.DebitorProductID == debitorProducts.ID))).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from delegation in context.MainLawyerDelegation.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.ID == delegationDebitorProduct.MainLawyerDelegationID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from debitorType in context.DebitorType.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.ID == debitor.DebitorTypeID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from exchangeType in context.ExchangeType.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && (item.ExchangeTypeID.HasValue && p.ID == (int)item.ExchangeTypeID)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from insertedAccountUser in context.AccountUser.Where(p => p.ID == item.InsertedBy).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from insertedAccountPerson in context.AccountPerson.Where(p => p.ID == insertedAccountUser.PersonID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from updatedAccountUser in context.AccountUser.Where(p => p.ID == item.UpdatedBy).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from updatedAccountPerson in context.AccountPerson.Where(p => p.ID == updatedAccountUser.PersonID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where
                         (!search.DebitorID.HasValue || debitor.ID == search.DebitorID)
                         && (search.DebitorNo == null || debitor.DebitorNo == search.DebitorNo)
                         && (search.TCKNOrTaxOfficeNumber == null || debitor.TCKN == search.TCKNOrTaxOfficeNumber || debitor.TaxOfficeNumber == search.TCKNOrTaxOfficeNumber)
                         && (search.FirstName == null || debitor.Name.Contains(search.FirstName))
                         && (search.Surname == null || debitor.Surname.Contains(search.Surname))
                         && (search.BankCode == null || context.DebitorProducts.Any(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.DebitorID == debitor.ID && p.TrackingUnitCode == search.BankCode))
                         && (search.PhoneNo == null || context.DebitorPhones.Any(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.DebitorID == debitor.ID && p.PhoneNo.Contains(search.PhoneNo)))
                         && (search.ExecutionFileNo1 == null || context.ExecutionTracking.Any(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.DebitorID == debitor.ID && p.ExecutionFileNo.StartsWith(search.ExecutionFileNo1.ToString())))
                         && (search.ExecutionFileNo2 == null || context.ExecutionTracking.Any(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.DebitorID == debitor.ID && p.ExecutionFileNo.EndsWith(search.ExecutionFileNo2.ToString())))
                         && (!search.LawyerID.HasValue || !delegationDebitorProduct.IsDeleted && delegation.Status == (int)LawyerConfirmStatus.Accept && (delegation.MainLawyerID == search.LawyerID || delegation.ObserverLawyerID == search.LawyerID))
                         && (!lawyerID.HasValue || !delegationDebitorProduct.IsDeleted && delegation.Status == (int)LawyerConfirmStatus.Accept && (delegation.MainLawyerID == lawyerID || delegation.ObserverLawyerID == lawyerID))
                         && ((!(context.AccountRole.Where(p => p.KimyonCode == "B" || p.KimyonCode == "SP" || p.KimyonCode == "SM").Select(p => p.ID).Contains(UserData.iRoleId))) || hyDepList.Contains(debitorProducts.TrackingUnitCode.ToString()))
                         && ((!(context.AccountRole.Where(p => p.KimyonCode == "MM" || p.KimyonCode == "MTL" || p.KimyonCode == "MP").Select(p => p.ID).Contains(UserData.iRoleId))) || associatedDepartmenList.Contains(debitorProducts.TrackingUnitCode.ToString()))
                        select new DebitorProductCautionsEx
                        {
                            ID = item.ID,
                            DebitorID = debitor.ID,
                            DebitorProductsID = item.DebitorProductsID,
                            ExchangeTypeID = item.ExchangeTypeID,
                            NotaryName = item.NotaryName,
                            ReferenceNo = item.ReferenceNo,
                            DailyChargeNo = item.DailyChargeNo,
                            CautionDate = item.CautionDate,
                            CautionPeriod = item.CautionPeriod,
                            NotificationDate = item.NotificationDate,
                            BankStatementDate = item.BankStatementDate,
                            BSMVRate = item.BSMVRate,
                            KKDFRate = item.KKDFRate,
                            CautionAmount = item.CautionAmount,
                            CapitalAmount = item.CapitalAmount,
                            InterestAmount = item.InterestAmount,
                            CommissionAmount = item.CommissionAmount,
                            LegalWageCutAmount = item.LegalWageCutAmount,
                            CautionCashAmount = item.CautionCashAmount,
                            CautionNonCashAmount = item.CautionNonCashAmount,
                            TotalDebt = item.TotalDebt,
                            MistralCustomerStatusID = debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID,
                            DebitorNo = debitor.DebitorNo,
                            DebitorName = (debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 3 || debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 8) ? debitor.Name.Replace(" ", "") + " " + debitor.Surname.Replace(" ", "") : debitor.Name,
                            DebitorSurname = debitor.Surname,
                            TCKN = debitor.TCKN,
                            NCN = debitor.NCN,
                            isKurumsal = (debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID != 3 && debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID != 8),
                            ProductName = (debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 3 || debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 8) ? product2.ProductName : (item.DebitorProductsID == 0 ? "KURUMSAL KREDİ" : product.ProductName),
                            ExchangeType = exchangeType.Description,
                            BSMV = (debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 3 || debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 8) ? (item.InterestAmount.HasValue ? Math.Truncate(((item.InterestAmount.Value * 5) / 100) * 100) / 100 : 0) : 0,
                            KKDF = (debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 3 || debitor.MistralCustomerStatusID == 8) ? (item.InterestAmount.HasValue ? Math.Truncate(((item.InterestAmount.Value * 15) / 100) * 100) / 100 : 0) : 0,
                            UpdateDate = item.UpdateDate,
                            InsertedBy = item.InsertedBy,
                            UpdatedBy = item.UpdatedBy,
                            InsertDate = item.InsertDate,
                            IsDeleted = item.IsDeleted,
                            InsertedName = insertedAccountPerson.FirstName.Trim() + " " + insertedAccountPerson.LastName.Trim(),
                            UpdatedName = updatedAccountPerson.FirstName.Trim() + " " + updatedAccountPerson.LastName.Trim()
                        };

            if (IsInDetailTab.Value)
            {
                return query;
            }

            var bireysel = new List<int>(); // Müşteri Tipi Bireysel olan ihtar ID'leri listesi.
            var kurumsal = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // Müşteri Tipi Kurumsal olan İhtarların DebitorId ve Yevmiye No'ya göre gruplanmış listesi.
//porblem is query non-static method
            **foreach (var item in query.OrderByDescending(p => p.ID).ToList())**
            {
                var deb = context.Debitor.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == item.DebitorID);
                if (deb != null && (deb.MistralCustomerStatusID == 3 || deb.MistralCustomerStatusID == 8))
                {
                    bireysel.Add(item.ID);
                    continue;
                }
                var key = string.Concat(item.DebitorID, "-", item.DailyChargeNo);
                if (kurumsal.ContainsKey(key))
                    continue;
                kurumsal.Add(key, item.ID);
            }
            var datKurumsal = query.Where(p => kurumsal.Values.Contains(p.ID));
            var datBireysel = query.Where(p => bireysel.Contains(p.ID));

            return datBireysel.Union(datKurumsal);
        }
```

Comment: firstlty sorry about my english, but my query like this and this 2 part only 1 query and i need solve this question ty..

Comment: this query given me some filter(debitor) and i am using in layout page this filter on header partial. when i change the page to sale this filter still in header. by the way i have clear button (filter clear). When i change the page anyone and click the clear button error is non-static method about query

Comment: Okay, without looking at the "too much code" , it's probably a .HasValue which is not supported